# RewriteRule from mod_rewrite only works as redirect with added http://%{HTTP_HOST}, but doesn't work at all without it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, otrs

I use [this](https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/rel-6_0/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf) apache config file on centOs 7. This file is is already set up to run

```
/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/customer.pl
```

on my machine on a call to
    http://localhost/opt/customer.pl

I wanted to use mod_rewrite to run the customer.pl and give it the called url as a parameter.
So i want to enter the url:
    localhost/HTMLData/1/Default.htm

and have it call:

```
/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/customer.pl
```

with the parameters

```
?Action=CustomerHTML;Subaction=ContentCall;Target=1/Default.htm
```

That works somewhat with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/HTMLData/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/otrs/customer.pl?Action=CustomerHTML;Subaction=ContentCall;Target=$1
```

But i this is a redirect (because of the added "http://%{HTTP_HOST}").
What i need is, that the webrowser keeps thinking http://localhost/HTMLData/1/ is where to get the files.
But if i remove the "http://%{HTTP_HOST}", it doesn't work at all. But the examples i found on the internet said i should work this way. What do i have to change, to have the redirect only internaly without giving the browser the real url back?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else might need this in the future.
What fixed it for me was adding

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
```

under "". I don't know why, but at least i can use the internal redirect now.